# How can I add a sublabel to a static venn.js chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, venn.js

I was told about the [Venn.js](https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/) script on GitHub, which uses javascript to create Venn diagrams on an html page.

I have a basic script working, but I would like to add a sublabel in each set and intersection that shows its size

```
    function LoadVenn() {            
        // size values are variables filled by an $.ajax() function.
        // this is called in the $.ajax() success block.
        var sets = [
                    { sets: ['Less than Quarter'], size: ltq },
                    { sets: ['Quarter'], size: qtr },
                    { sets: ['Semester'], size: sem },
                    { sets: ['Year'], size: year },
                    { sets: ['Less than Quarter', 'Quarter'], size: ltqQtr },
                    { sets: ['Less than Quarter', 'Semester'], size: ltqSem },
                    { sets: ['Less than Quarter', 'Year'], size: ltqYear }
        ];

        // the chart is accurately created.
        var chart = venn.VennDiagram();
        d3.select("#venn").datum(sets).call(chart);

        // fill colors are good.
        d3.selectAll("#venn .venn-circle path").style("fill-opacity", 0.8);
        d3.selectAll("#venn text").style("fill", "white");

        // need to make label text larger
        // need to add sublabel showing set size
    }
```

I did find a sublabel example [here](https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/blob/master/examples/sublabels.html), but it was for an endlessly cycling animation chart (which I didn't want).

How can I add a sublabel to a static and non-animated chart?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of what you have? Why don't you just use the code in the example? It is just an infinite cycle run by `setInterval();`

Comment: I just set up a new fiddle account so I could post it there. However, there there is no URI for the external resources I need, so I have to figure out how to do that now.

Comment: Use those in the example you posted https://jsfiddle.net/cdt130v3/

Comment: I tried the link you just posted, but even script copied straight from the venn.js site (like simple.html) isn't responding. Not sure.  And as for "why didn't i just use the code in the [sublabel] example, I actually tried to extract code from it, just to add the sublabel text. No browser errors, but no chart rendered at all.

Comment: It runs correctly to me https://jsfiddle.net/cdt130v3/4/

Comment: I'm trying a different approach. I'm using the Chrome "inspect" to identify the specific elements in the SVG and use jQuery to append the text that way. It might be simpler (for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the animated sublabels example and a sample code from [here](https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/issues/46):

```js
var sets = [
  {sets:["Information"], size: 12},
  {sets:["Overlap"], size: 12},
  {sets:["Circles"], size: 12},
  {sets: ["Information", "Overlap"], size: 4, label: "Redundancy"}
];
    
var chart = venn.VennDiagram()
    .wrap(false)
    .fontSize("16px")
    .width(640)
    .height(640);
    
function annotateSizes() {
    d3.select(this).select("text")
        .append("tspan")
        .text(function(d) { return "size " + d.size; })
        .attr("x", function() { return d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("x"); })
        .attr("dy", "1.5em")
        .style("fill", "#666")
        .style("font-size", "10px");
}     

function updateVenn(sets) {
    var div = d3.select("#venn").datum(sets);
    var layout = chart(div),
        textCentres = layout.textCentres;
    div.selectAll(".label").style("fill", "white");
    div.selectAll(".venn-circle path").style("fill-opacity", .6);

 div.selectAll("g").transition("venn").each("end", annotateSizes).duration(0);
        
    return layout;
}

updateVenn(sets);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/benfred/venn.js/master/venn.js"></script>


<div id="venn"></div>
```

Comment: Aha!  So this was the magic key I was missing when trying append the text labels in a different approach.. `d3.select(this).select("text").append("tspan")`